# printf-style logger that is non-variadic

Tags: c++, variadic-functions, variadic-macros

Our C/C++ project is using a new internal script that liberally wraps every function in SWIG to make available to python scripts.  It chokes on our logger function since SWIG cannot wrap variadic functions well.

So I decided to hide the variadic functionality in a macro that SWIG will never trip over, shown in a simplified example below:

```c
#include <iostream>

void LogPrint(char *file, int line, char* msg)
{
    std::cout << file << ":" << line;
    std::cout << " [ " << msg << " ] ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

#define MAX_LOG 256

#define LogPrintf(msg, args...) \
{ \
    char *msg_buffer = new char[MAX_LOG]; \
    snprintf(msg_buffer, MAX_LOG, msg, ##args); \
    Log(__FILE__, __LINE__, msg_buffer); \
    delete [] msg_buffer; \
}

main()
{
    LogPrintf("%s = %f", "tau", 6.28318);
    LogPrintf("%s = %f", "pi", 3.14159);
}
```

Is this okay? Are there better solutions to this problem?  Thanks.

Comment: There is no such thing like C/C++ and both are really different about variadic macros. Your code is C++ but you are tagging your question with C. Please chose one, or explain better what your are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python makes it trivial to assemble formatted strings within Python, so I would just offer the simple "give me a string and I log it" error.

For the general case, though, you might consider:

1) boost::format

2) emulating the iostream interface by creating a class that holds a `std::stringstream` member, overloading `operator<<` to forward to the stringstream's `operator<<`, and then adding some other way to actually log the "buffer" contents (one approach is to log in the destructor of the object - making it non-copyable is probably a good idea - so you can do something like `Logger() << "foo" << bar;` - the temporary object lifetime is extended to the end of the line, the operator overloads build up the buffer contents, and then the dtor runs and outputs the `.str()` of the stringstream to whereever).

Comment: Thanks for the different options.  Good ideas.

Comment: This question is tagged C++. How did you arrive at a Python answer?